# Find next file in a folder

Tags: python, performance, file, directory, os.path

my way of getting the name of the next file in a folder is just terrible but works.I would like to remove the requirement of calling the os.listdir function as it is slow in large folders but dont know how. Any help is welcome.

Note:
Fullpathtoimagefile is the old file
changeimage is the name of a function that gets the next file

```
def nextfile(self):
    folder, filename = os.path.split(fullpathtoimagefile)
    filelist = os.listdir(folder)
    nextfile = filelist.index(filename) + 1
    nextfilename = filelist[nextfile]
    changeimage(os.path.join(folder, nextfilename))
```

tl;dr More efficient way to get the full name of the next file in a folder

Comment: Can you call `os.listdir()` just once, and save the results on self?  Although if a file has been created/removed in the meantime, I don't see how you will avoid calling `listdir()` again.

Comment: Did not expect this to move so fast. Clarification:  The usecase is clicking on a file in a folder and clicking nextimage. The filter for the file format may change after every image. That calls os.listdir and is very slow. What annoys me: The OS already has that exact filelist in memory and it is used to disply the files in order. Is there a purepython way to get at that list so i dont have to call os.listdir.

Comment: `os.listdir()` is the pure python way to get the contents of a directory.  It sounds like you're using a library that insists on calling `listdir()` too often?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can work with this one out.

```
 [(os.path.join(folder, d), d, os.path.isdir(os.path.join(folder, d ))) for d in os.listdir(folder)]
```

Answer (score 0):

simple code..

```
import os

arq = (os.listdir(".")) # "." = directory name
for file in arq:
    print(file)
```

Another example:

```
import os

arq = (os.listdir("."))
for file in arq:
    if (os.path.splitext(file)[1] == ".jpg"): #if a JPG file, do something
        print(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of smells like an instance of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It looks like you're trying to iterate over images in a folder - in that case, use the `pathlib` module (it's been around since Python 3.4):

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path("path/to/folder/with/images").glob("*.jpg"):
    print(path)
```